# How does npm list know which ones are direct dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Get into a new directly, after typing those three commands:

```
npm install underscore
npm install lodash
npm install express
```

I get a `node_modules` directory with many packages:

```
$ ls node_modules

accepts              cookie-signature  encodeurl     forwarded    lodash             mime-db      parseurl        send            underscore
array-flatten        debug             escape-html   fresh        media-typer        mime-types   path-to-regexp  serve-static    unpipe
content-disposition  depd              etag          http-errors  merge-descriptors  ms           proxy-addr      setprototypeof  utils-merge
content-type         destroy           express       inherits     methods            negotiator   qs              statuses        vary
cookie               ee-first          finalhandler  ipaddr.js    mime               on-finished  range-parser    type-is
```

While using `npm list`, I can get a tree strcture:

```
$ npm list
/tmp/play/npm
├─┬ express@4.14.0
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.3
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.13
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.25.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.1
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.1
│ ├── content-type@1.0.2
│ ├── cookie@0.3.1
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── depd@1.1.0
│ ├── encodeurl@1.0.1
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
│ ├── etag@1.7.0
│ ├─┬ finalhandler@0.5.0
│ │ ├── statuses@1.3.1
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
│ ├── fresh@0.3.0
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
│ ├── methods@1.1.2
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.1.2
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.1.1
│ ├── qs@6.2.0
│ ├── range-parser@1.2.0
│ ├─┬ send@0.14.1
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.5.1
│ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.3
│ │ │ └── setprototypeof@1.0.2
│ │ └── mime@1.3.4
│ ├── serve-static@1.11.1
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.6.14
│ │ └── media-typer@0.3.0
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
│ └── vary@1.1.0
├── lodash@4.17.2
└── underscore@1.8.3
```

My question is: **from all those dependencies, how does `npm list` know which ones are my direct dependencies such as `undersocre`, `lodash` and `express`?**

note: I don't have a `package.json` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It builds the list on the basis of the dependencies of the modules. The dependencies of the modules are specified in the `package.json` of each module in the `dependencies` field. When you install a module `npm` adds some additional fields to the module's `package.json` and one of those is the field `_requiredBy` to store the dependency link in the other direction as well. If you run the `npm list` command it goes through all the modules and reads the `_requiredBy` field in `package.json` of each module.

If you install a module directly without saving it to your `package.json`, `npm` adds `#USER` to the `_requiredBy` field to signify that you manually installed it and it is not just a dependency of the other modules. Then `npm list` shows that module in the root of the tree as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
npm list --depth=0 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

`npm list` command will print to stdout all the versions of packages that are installed, as well as their dependencies, in a tree-structure.

So you have only installed three packages

```
npm install underscore
npm install lodash
npm install express
```

All other packages are dependency for `express` package